# Cubism with genomic data (or non-timeseries data)

Tags: d3.js, cubism.js

I'd like to hear your thoughts on what would it take to make cubism work with non timeseries data, concretely, genomic data.

These type of data has a locus (a chromosome and coordinates within that chromosome) instead of a timestamp:

```
chrm1 145678123 value
chrm12 45345 value
chrmX 4535 value
....
```

What option do you think is best, hacking cubism's core to allow for these type of data (or any type of data for that matter) or spawning a new project all together?

UPDATE: I decided to implement a modified version of cubism for DNA. I call it DNAism and you can find it [here](https://github.com/drio/dnaism). Take a look and let me know what you think.

-drd

Comment: I'm working on a similar problem: how to display genomic data via d3. Would be interested in the solution.

Comment: Check my solution [here](https://github.com/drio/dnaism).

Answer (score 2):

Cubism is probably not the right kind of library for this task. You're going to have to modify the library in a pretty significant way. Instead of doing that I'd recommend you use the [d3.horizon](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1483226) plugin so that you can gain a lot more control by creating custom scales.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The changes maybe hard to make but the problem that cubism solve is basically the same compare to what I am trying to do. I am currently going over the code. Let's see if someone else weighs in.